# How connect to a ssh server from Nautilus on startup automatically?

Tags: nautilus, ssh, startup, connection

I try to connect to the server from the startup automatically. How could I do it to see the server files on Nautilus?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I will write it anyway. Run `Connect to server...` and connect as usual. You can select remember password when asked. When connected, you can bookmark the location with `Ctrl + D`. Next time when you boot, just go to the location that you bookmarked. If you didn't choose to remember your password, you will be asked to enter it. Also, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, so I'm not sure if this will be useful to you. Anyway, I hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Just used this today. The solution still works awesomely on ubuntu 15.04 and connecting to amazon ec2 server. Thanks.